# NavigationDrawer - is it possible to simulate (perform) click programmatically

Tags: android

Im using the NavigationDrawer in my app and I wonder is it possible that I performClick on some of the navigation drawer list items the way it is possible for a button?

```
    slideMenuItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerModel>();

    slideMenuItems.add(new NavDrawerModel("People"));
    slideMenuItems.add(new NavDrawerModel("Products"));

slideMenuAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item, slideMenuItems);
    drawerList.setAdapter(slideMenuAdapter);

    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());


private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do some stuff here

    }
```

Comment: Just call their function what you call on clicking them.

Comment: its complicated. every button starts a different sequence of database operations and actions that are tangled up in the navigation menu, so I cant extract them as methods and it would be lots of code repetition if I rewrite them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`performItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick%28android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) in the `ListView`

```
public boolean performItemClick (View view, int position, long id)

Added in API level 1

Call the OnItemClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

Parameters

view    The view within the AdapterView that was clicked.
position    The position of the view in the adapter.
id  The row id of the item that was clicked.

Returns
True if there was an assigned OnItemClickListener that was called, false otherwise is returned.
```

How to use:

```
int position = 5;
listView.performItemClick( 
   yourAdapter.getView(position, null, null),
   position,
   yourAdapter.getItemId(position)
);
```

Remember to override `getItemId` correctly if you use a custom adapter!